# Limit of $n\log(1 −1/n)$ as n approaches infinity: Why is it not zero?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I understand the answer is $-1$.

But I can't get there.

If I apply L'hopital's rule, I get:

${{1}\over{n - 1}} + \log({{n-1}\over{n}})$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}$ of the first part is $0$.

The second part is also zero.

So I assume $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ is zero.

However, it is $-1$. Can someone help me understand?

Comment: yes, thanks, let me edit

Comment: Your usage of L'hopital's rule is not appropriate. Limit of $f(n)$ isn't equal to limit of $f'(n)$.

Comment: This is essentially the definition of log, right? The definition of $e^x$ I know is $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n$ and the definition of $\log$ I know is the inverse of $e^x$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$n \log \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{ \log \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac 1 n}$$ Now, using L'Hospital
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) n^2}}{-\frac1 {n^2} }=-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}\to -1$$

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
(-\dfrac{\log (1-1/n)-\log(1)}{(-1/n)})= -(\log (x))'_{x=1}=-1$

Answer (score 2):

A Taylor series expansion is the obvious way to see this.
$$-\log(1-1/n) = {1\over n}+{1\over 2n^2} +{1 \over 3n^3}+...$$
So
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\log(1-1/n)=-1$$